# Reboot touchphone without touching the screen

Tags: reboot

Sometimes touch screen on my phone is swithced off and does not switch on again. The phone is working, you can ring it, even the touch keys have light.

Can you say, it there a method how to reboot it not touching the screen?

My phone is I-Mobile IQ 5.5 (bought in Thailand).
OS: Android 4.2.2.

I've searched the phone's manual, there is nothing about this topic.

I know there is a combination of keys from other manufacturers like Samsung, but as I said here there were no word about it in manual.

Maybe there is an app, which can help me reboot the phone by pressing several hard keys?

Now, I am just taking off the battery to reboot the phone.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem honestly.  The process of rebooting an Android phone depends entirely on the hardware itself.

Comment: hold power button ?

Comment: Have you tried `adb reboot`?

Comment: Yep, I was trying (it works), but I don't need the solution with smartphone connected to computer.

Answer (score 4):

Pressing and holding the phone's power button for a few seconds might do the trick.

It switches off my Android phones.

Comment: yea, hold it for a long time, 10seconds for this one, 15seconds for my old thing. cool, i had forgot that.

Comment: I've hold it for 30 seconds. No reboot.
Only the menu for reboot, shotdow, scrennsho, etc. appeared.

Comment: @Alex Does your phone have the ability to connect to USB devices like a keyboard and mouse? I once used this method to help someone get stuff off of their phone after they smashed the screen.

Comment: @ chritohnide No. But can you point me to this information about reboot with keyboard? Just interesting .

Comment: @Alex I don't have a link, but I can explain: fortunately there was an adaptor device for the phone (galaxy s 2) that plugged into the phone's micro-USB port and provided a full size USB port into which I was able to plug a keyboard and mouse (via a hub). This then allowed me to interact with the phone. Presumably, you'd be able to shutdown the phone in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Total noob with this stuff myself, I have been reading around,
Some applications given access like admin(?) , will have been allowed to install in critical locations to do the special tricks they do.
To fully remove these applications the special permission change made has to be disabled by the program first, then the program itself can be uninstalled.

If the program was allowed (the special permission) to make changes to critical section, then removed without the permission, it is possible for critical changes to be left.  (source: fails done by commenters in google play store)
 Anytime these high permissions are allowed, and these changes made, it should be turned back off first in the program, prior to uninstalling the program, or unexpected things could occur.

It is possible that a cool trick software has been installed, and forgotten, or not un-installed properly.  Maybe an app that turns the screen on or off based on sencors or cameras , or phone or messages, like the proximity, or a shake , docking ?  That the application has made changes, or even changes to more critical areas.  Lock screen app, lock screen customiser, launcher , special trick home changes, there are hundreds of less documented tricks.

There are "safe Mode" ways of getting into the phones which keeps 3rd party items from operating, the https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=safe+mode Android site has lots of information on it.
Also
 The search of https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=boot+loop Bootloop.  We know you do not have a boot loop, but you still cant do much when this happens, so some of the boot loop information could be applied, which is this safe mode.

Different phones use slightly different methods for getting into the safemode, adding to the fun, finding an expert with the same phone might be a thing to do if you wanted to access safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

My android LG phone had the same problem. I tried the power button, with no success. Then I took of the back cover and then removed the battery, then put it back in. Next, I held the power button down. This rebooted the phone back up. Hope this works for you, and good luck!